# Tableau Calculation - String

Tags: tableau-api, calculation

[image: This is my data]

I want output which consists of the count of familycode and output should be like below

[image]

so baically i need three category first will be single and multiple only ASK product count . 2nd will be Single ASK and single NON ask count and third one WIth only SIngle ASK .....  and ignore the other - categroy such as multiple NON ASK and ASK and NON ASK mIX.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question in respect to grammar, spelling and punctuation, so people who are non-natives can understand your question better.

Comment: Rather than a question this is more like a homework